# nginx reverse proxy to different port on another server running Apache/WordPress

Tags: wordpress, nginx, proxy, apache2, reverse-proxy

I am trying to setup nginx as a reverse proxy from one debian environment, to another debian environment. The two environments are on different IPs, and in different locations. Here is my configuration on the nginx reverse proxy.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name foo.domain.com domain.com;
  root /var/www;

  if ($http_host != "foo.bar.com") {
    rewrite ^ foo.bar.com$request_uri permanent;
  }

  index index.php index.html index.htm;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://bar.domain.com:2000/;
    proxy_redirect http://bar.domain.com http://foo.domain.com/;
  }
}
```

Apache wordpress site is working on http://bar.domain.com:2000, however http://foo.domain.com does not transfer to it. When using foo.domain.com the address changes to foo.domain.com:2000 after it times out.

Comment: What happens if you remove the "if ... rewrite ..." block?

Comment: Nothing changes if I remove that part. I've been working on this for so long that I honestly forgot why I put that in there.

Comment: I know the feeling! Try to further isolate the problem by removing other entries in your config if you can. If you get it to work, begin adding them back.

Comment: Remove `if` and `proxy_redirect`

Comment: I have removed everything except for:
server {
    listen: 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://bar.domain.com:2000/;
    }
}

And it doesn't help at all.

Comment: @Zerono Did you ever find a solution? Because I am facing the same issue. The problem is that WordPress does a redirect to a URL. There are two settings in WorPress defining the blog's URL. They are located in the wp_options table and they are called "siteurl" and "home". I am not sure which one is used for the redirection.